# Is it independent or not? Why and why not?

Tags: probability

I came across with this kind of question from Probability and got confused.

Question is:

**In a box there is a red ball and a green ball. We draw a ball three times with replacement.
Let event A be „we draw a red ball exactly twice” 
and event B be „we draw a red ball on the first draw”. 
Are events A and B independent? Why/why not?**

I explored and found these:

*Two events A and B are independent if the knowledge that one occurred does not affect the chance the other occurs. For example, the outcomes of two roles of a fair die are independent events. The outcome of the first roll does not change the probability for the outcome of the second roll.
In formulas:
Two events are independent if the following are true:

P(A|B) = P(A)

P(B|A) = P(B)

P(A AND B) = P(A)P(B)
*

But my question is much more complex than that.

Please help me, thanks you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to calculate $P(A \cap B), P(A)$ and $P(B)$? Is there any problem with that?

Comment: These things are what I'm struggling in, Could you help?

Comment: $P(A)=3\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$ Is it comprehensible?

Comment: Sorry, I had to change my previous comment.

Comment: Then, P(B) is the same like P(A)?

Comment: Bro, Could you give me full answer with explanation, of course if you have time

Comment: I´ve posted an answer. I hope it is comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At event A we have three ways to draw a red ball exactly twice: $\color{red}r\color{red}r\color{green}g, \color{red}r\color{green}g\color{red}r, \color{green}g\color{red}r\color{red}r$. Each way has a probability of  $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac18$. Thus $P(A)=\frac38$

And the probability of drawing  a red ball on the first draw is just $P(B)=\frac12$. This is the sequence $\color{red}rxx$, where $x$ can be a red ball or a green ball.

The intersection of the two events are the sequences $\color{red}r\color{red}r\color{green}g$ and $ \color{red}r\color{green}g\color{red}r$.  Both sequences have a red ball at the first place. Thus $P(A\cap B)=2\cdot \frac18=\frac28$

Finally it is easy to see that $P(A)\cdot P(B)\neq P(A\cap B)$.